# What does the symbol $\operatorname{Tr}$ in the Yang-Mills action mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I find that many authors write the Yang-Mills action as follows:
$$\mathcal{J}= \int \operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge  \star F).$$
I have yet to find a formal description of the symbol $\operatorname{Tr}$ and am especially interested in its relation to differential geometry. How should I understand it?

Answer (score 18):

*We choose the physics convention
$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu - i g [A_\mu,A_\nu]$, where the generators of the Lie algebra are Hermitian.
In this case the integral has a minus sign,
$\mathcal{J} = -\int \operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge  * F)$.*

The first thing to note is that $F$ has vector *and* Lie algebra indices.
The trace is over the Lie algebra, *not* over the vector indices.
The vector indices are just like those of the field strength in QED.
In Yang-Mills the field strength (also called the curvature form) is Lie algebra valued.
In this case $F_{\mu\nu} = F_{\mu\nu}^a T^a$, where the summation convention is used, and where the $T^a$ are the generators of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.
To be explicit, $F$ has not only tensor components but matrix components
$$(F_{\mu\nu})_{ij} = F_{\mu\nu}^a T^a_{ij}.$$

The inner product of $F$ with itself is by definition $(F,F) = \int F\wedge * F$ where $*$ is the Hodge $*$ operator.
Thus, we are calculating $\mathcal{J} = -\operatorname{Tr}(F,F)$.
It is a standard exercise to find the exterior product of two $r$-forms.
We find
$$F\wedge * F  = \frac{1}{2!} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^4.$$
Note that the differential forms don't "know" the Lie algebra.
The algebra hasn't come into the calculation yet.

From here we must calculate the trace of $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Tr} \left(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\right)
&=& \operatorname{Tr} \left( F_{\mu\nu}^a T^a F^{\mu\nu b}T^b\right) \\
&=& \operatorname{Tr}\left(T^a T^b\right)
 F_{\mu\nu}^a F^{\mu\nu b} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \delta^{a b}
 F_{\mu\nu}^a F^{\mu\nu b} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\nu}^a F^{\mu\nu a},
\end{eqnarray}$$
where we have used the standard normalization convention for the $T^a$, 
$\operatorname{Tr} T^a T^b = \frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$. 
(This comes from the fact that we want $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ to live naturally in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, and the generators of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ are taken to be $T^a = \sigma^a/2$, where $\sigma^a$ are the Pauli matrices.) 
Thus, we find
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{J} &=& -\int \operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge  * F) \\
&=& -\frac{1}{4} \int d^4x \, F_{\mu\nu}^a F^{\mu\nu a}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned this is just the trace on matrices.  But the following viewpoint may help to see where this is coming from. $F$ lives in the tensor product space $su(2) \otimes \Omega^2(M)$ of the Lie algebra $su(2)$ with $2$-forms.  $\Omega^2(M)$ has an inner product given by the $L^2$ inner product and $su(2)$ has a unique (up to scale) Ad-invariant inner product given by the Killing form, which is really just $(A,B) \mapsto tr(AB)$ viewing $A, B \in su(2)$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices.  Taking the induced inner product on the tensor product, the expression you wrote is the norm squared of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the trace and it's being taken over the vector space of the fields $F$.

Comment: Thank you! I see, then $F{\wedge}{\star}F$ should be viewed as a linear operator...This way it makes sense ...

Comment: @Autolatry: It is not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: @oenamen Sir, to provide extra explanation would require repetition of your excellent post.

Comment: @oen: What do you mean? Seems clear to me    $  \mbox{ }  :\int$.